# Пунктуация в стихотворении Пушкина

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, сложное-предложение

*Кто видел край, где роскошью природы

Оживлены дубравы и луга,

**Где весело шумят и блещут воды

И мирные ласкают берега,**

Где на холмы под лавровые своды

Не смеют лечь угрюмые снега?

Скажите мне: кто видел край прелестный,

Где я любил, изгнанник неизвестный?*
А. С. Пушкин

Почему в выделенной части предложения отсутствуют запятые?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 4):

Где весело **шумят и блещут** воды **и** мирные **ласкают** берега.

Здесь три однородных сказуемых, но смысловая связь между сказуемыми 1 и 2  более тесная, поэтому первый союз И соединяет эти сказуемые, а второй союз И связывает сказуемые 1, 2 со сказуемым 3. 
Поэтом **союзы И не относятся к повторяющимся, запятая не ставится**.